# Implementing video calling feature using facetime, (can't back to the application when call ended)

Tags: ios, facetime

I am trying to make a chatting application, text chatting using APNS and in my app here is another option for video calling. I am using facetime for video calling feature. I have a button name "Video Call", when press this button the following code executes:

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://someones_apple_id@gmail.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

It opens Facetime and call to someones_apple_id@gmail.com

My problem is when the call ended, my Application didn't launch automatically!

Problem in details: Suppose I have two iPad, that installed the same application. This application have a button called video call. The application is running on these two iPads. Now I am pressing video call button to call. Facetime opens in my iPad and the caller iPad. When call ended, my application didn't launch automatically but the receivers application launched automatically.

I tried the same thing in a UIWebView using the following code, but facing the same problem!

<(a href=\"facetime://someones_apple_id@gmail.com\">Video Call<(/a)>

My problem is from caller end, not in the receiver end. I want to back to my application when the call ended. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still didn't get the exact solution, but I have found a tricky one::

When call ended from caller end, touch your iPad with four fingers and swipe it down when the iPad is in Landscape mode. When your iPad is in portrait mode swipe it right using four fingers. Now you are seeing your application.

If it doesn't work, then you can swipe left/right/top/bottom using four fingers. One of these will work for you. Actually it depends in which orientation you are now browsing.

thanks.